# Rails query to make sure array doesn't contain nil objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the [public_activity gem](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) for notifications. I'm facing a problem where if a user get's notified about a new comment on their Post, their notifications will raise the error because that object is now nil since it's been deleted. I can combat this by making sure the trackable object is not nil with `<% if activity.trackable %>...render code...<% end %>`. However, I am also displaying the total number of notifications they have on the page with this query.

```
PublicActivity::Activity.order('created_at DESC').where(recipient_id: current_user, kind: "Notification", read: false).where('owner_id not in (?)', current_user).size
```

How can I get this to make sure it does *not* include the any activities where their `trackable` has been deleted.

Ex. User 1 created a post. User 2 comments on the post. User 1 has one notification that says "User 2 has commented on this Post". (Post is a link to the post). User 1 now deletes this post, but the activity has *not* been removed. Therefore, when I query the notification count, that activity will be included, even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if !activity_trackable.nil? %>
  you can add the code that gets the count here
<% else %>
  <%= 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is not answering my question. I need to include something in the query to get the count. If you read the first paragraph, I am already doing this, but in a different way. The question asks how to include something in the query. thanks.